# Bulk Unsubscribing Emails From Lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp, bulk, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using [feralchimp](https://github.com/envygeeks/feralchimp) gem as a ruby API wrapper for the Mailchimp API in my Rails (4) application.

What I need is to unsubscribe a large amount of emails from different lists through Mailchimp API, does anyone have an idea how to do so using this gem?

Currently we unsubscribe one email, from one list, using one API call, with this code:

```
Feralchimp.new.lists_unsubscribe(id: list_id, email: { email: email_to_unsubscribe })
```

But Mailchimp API [supports bulk operations](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-batch-operations/), and I can't find enough documentation for both the API and feralchimp the gem, and it would be just much efficient to unsubscribe a bulk of emails at once.

Comment: Do you mean how can you do it without making one call for each email + list combination? If that isn't an option, why not? If it is, why not give that a shot (with maybe a delayed job thing to do it in batches)? (I suspect there is a reason, I'm just curious about what it is.)

Comment: @alexanderbird I updated the question, is it clear now?

Comment: Yup, thanks for clarifying.